# How to make an RPM package (without rpmbuild)

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

deb:

```
fakeroot dpkb-build -b directory package.deb
# Name, version, architecture, etc. are in directory/DEBIAN/control
```

rpm:

```
$SOME_COMMAND directory package.rpm
# Name, version, architecture, etc. are in SOME_FILE
```

What to use as SOME_COMMAND and SOME_FILE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it is not clear what kind of RPM package you intend to build.  It is `.src.rpm` or a binary `.rpm`?

RPM packages have a file format.  This consists of a lead block, a number of header structures, a signature block, and an archive.  It's like a ZIP file, but it contains extra information in binary at the beginning to ensure that the package meta-data is stored and accessible for those who wish to query the package prior to installation.

So you can either [write a binary file according to the specification](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-file-format-rpm-file-format.html), or you can use the tools which guarantee the file is written according to the specification (namely rpmbuild).  I would highly recommend the latter, as an RPM is not "just another ZIP file" and it's not "just another tar file".  It has more structure than that, and the cost of rolling it "manually" eventually starts to incur the cost of redeveloping portions of rpmbuild.

Note that rpmbuild can be installed on systems that don't actually use RPM for their own internal package management.

Comment: Binary RPM. I want it to be the thing that puts files to the places I want and allows easy updating/uninstalling and where I can specify dependencies.

Comment: rpmbuild requires lengthy spec files (lengthier that simple deb control files), specific directory structure; it attempts to compile it from source code (assuming there is source code) and in general does too many things.

Comment: @Vi, if you want to use rpm, then the provided tool is `rpmbuild`  If you don't want to use that, then you must decide whether you want to take on the additional task of building a `rpmbuild` replacement or if you can just change your workflow to use the rpmbuild tool.  I doubt you'll roll a consistent package without rpmbuild, as there's a lot more going on than just "put it in the right archive format" with RPM.

Comment: @Vi, I can understand the complaint that spec files seem lengthy; however, they are not that lengthy (I often write 20 line spec files), and they ensure the integrity of the delivered package.  If don't want integrity, use Zip; but, the reason people use RPM is because they want the integrity.  Not just integrity of the archive, but integrity of the system pre and post archive installation.

Comment: @Vi, RPM assumes that the packager is not necessarily the software development group.  This means it is modeled for an antagonistic relationship between the packaging group and the dev group.  So every file to be delivered is listed in the spec file because that pesky developer might have removed a file (or the build might have failed without writing the file).  From the computer's point of view, it is not possible to know the difference.  From the packaging system's point of view, you want to automate repackaging.  That means a list has to be kept somewhere, and the .spec is where it is.

Comment: Can you provide example of spec file for case when Makefile has "make rpm" target, not rpmbuild initiates building of the code? To make `make` invoke creation of rpm package, not the reverse.

Comment: @Vi, put the entire compiled source in an archive.  Override the "build" command to extract the archive into the "build directory".  Keep your delivered files / required directories list up to date.  It really is that simple if you want to sidestep RPM's ability to build on the reference platform.  Note that doing so has a lot of dangers, mainly it doesn't guarantee against clib compatibility problems, and your `.src.rpm` package will be all but useless; however, it seems you don't care about making sure the code runs on the foreign platform.

Comment: @Vi, or if I were you, I would just rewrite the existing build system to deliver a "src package", put that in the RPM SOURCES directory, and bootstrap your build from within RPM.  That way you will get the right dependencies, the right binaries for the platform, and you will have a `.src.rpm` which you can put on other architectures to facilitate easy rpmbuild-ing there.

Comment: So complex... All that rightness-ensuring system is good, but may be simple things should also be provided? /* Trying to follow other tutorial to set up things to make proper usage of rpmbuild */